# Expand 1 element list in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming. I have performed an HTTP get request and stored the result in a dictionary (called `updates`) with the following structure:

```
updates = {u'ok': True, 
           u'result': [{u'message': {u'date': 151957, 
                                     u'text': u'light',    # <<< my flag
                                     u'from': {u'first_name': u'john', 
                                               u'last_name': u'doe', 
                                               u'is_up': False, 
                                               u'id': 67346734, 
                                               u'language_code': u'en-US'}, 
                                     u'message_id': 32333, 
                                     u'chat': {u'first_name': u'johns', 
                                               u'cant': u'tesla', 
                                               u'type': u'private', 
                                               u'id': 4343434471}}, 
                        u'update_id': 368723512862}]}
```

I made the request with the `.json()` function in order to get it in json format.

Now, I want to access certain elements. First I thought I needed to get the 'results'. So I did the following

```
helo = updates["result"]
```

and when I see the length of the list there is only one element (the whole `results` item, not separated by every result sub item.

I'm clearly not getting the idea of how to work properly with list and dictionaries. In particular, I need to trigger an action if the text value is `light` (please see the flagged part of the code).

May you please help me to understand?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`updates["result"]` is a list of dictionaries.
You will have to iterate through all of them and see if any of them have `'light'` for the `'text'` key:

```
results = updates["result"]
for result in results:
    if result['message']['text'] == 'light':
        print 'found light text'
```

If you are certain that you will always have a single result you can only check the first one:

```
result = updates["result"][0]
if result['message']['text'] == 'light':
    print 'found light text'
```

In this case you will want to use a `try-except` just in case you don't get back any result:

```
try:
    result = updates["result"][0]
except IndexError:
    print 'Empty result'
else:
    if result['message']['text'] == 'light':
        print 'found light text'
```

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list to get the required value.

**Ex:**

```
updates = {u'ok': True, u'result': [{u'message': {u'date': 151957, u'text': u'light', u'from': {u'first_name': u'john', u'last_name': u'doe', u'is_up': False, u'id': 67346734, u'language_code': u'en-US'}, u'message_id': 32333, u'chat': {u'first_name': u'johns', u'cant': u'tesla', u'type': u'private', u'id': 4343434471}}, u'update_id': 368723512862}]}
for i in updates["result"]:
    print(i["message"]["text"])
```

**Output:**

```
light
```

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `message` and `text` keys are always present and you have only to check `light` value, you can just to specify it as inline for an `if` ... `else` statement:

```
>>> any([e for e in updates["result"] if e["message"]["text"] == "light"])
True
```